# mysql selection

Tags: mysql, select

I have one table - Users - and I have another table - Colors. Every user can create more records in Colors and each of these are "owned" by the user in question (this means that Colors holds a field named "Userid", which is the same as the field named "Id" in the Users table).

Example:
User Per has created these records in Colors:
Red 
Blue
Black

User Phil has created the record in Colors.
Blue

Now I want to select the users that have created BOTH Blue and Red. Can I do this in one select statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try (example, modify according to your table structure!):

```
SELECT X.UserID FROM 
(SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT COLOR) C FROM COLORS WHERE COLOR IN ( 'Red', 'Blue' ) GROUP BY UserID) X 
WHERE X.C = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can :)

Hint: it'll probably involve a "join".

Q: What have you tried so far?

Q: Is this a homework assignment?  We can help you find the answer - but we can't just GIVE you the answer...

Comment: So you admit *this* is not an answer? Why don't you post it as a comment then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in one select statement. Perhaps offer the tables stucture and your attempt if you cannot get this to work.